# Team Explorer - Builds shows "(X) Not Found"

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

First day trying new VS `Community 2015 RC Version 14.0.22823.1 D14REL`.
Our TFS server is still TFS 2010; I'm wondering if that's the source of the problem.

Other Team Explorer sections are working fine -- Work Items, Source Control Explorer, Pending Changes. I even did a merge and checkin successfully.

But the Builds section shows this:

[image: Builds section shows "Not Found"]

I'm not even sure where to look for an error log.

VS.NET 2012, still installed on the machine, shows the Builds section correctly.

Comment: Is it TFS2010 or TFS2010 SP1?

Comment: Not SP1 as far as I can tell. `Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 (30319.01)`.  I'm downloading SP1 now and will update the question with results when it's installed.

Comment: TFS server refused to let me install SP1.

Comment: As TFS 2010 drops it off mainstream support in july 2015 you should upgrade to 2013 or better yet 2015.

Comment: I am running TFS 2010 and have the exact same issue. Seems to be a VS 2015 and 2010 problem. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling VS 2015 after my Windows 10 debacle, I found that suddenly everything was working including builds! With the server still on TFS 2010. Apparently my problem was that I had the VS 2015 Community *Release Candidate*, not the final release.

Answer (score 0):

As support for TFS 2010 ends before VS 2015 releases don't expect the support to be awesome. If you don't have SP1 then your are already out of support. None of the editions of Visual Studio 2015 (and 2013) officially support TFS 2010 RTM.

I would recommend that you upgrade to TFS 2013, or TFS 2015 at your earliest opportunity. If you need support for that then get a consultant to help who has a good relationship with MSFT.

If your ops team is inside of keeping software up to that's and with the applications support model then you should seriously consider moving to VSO so that you don't have to worry about It any more.